# Is there a point of defining the reaction rate as the rate of disappearing of a reactant **over its coefficent**?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

$$aA+bB \rightarrow cC + dD$$
The reaction rate is defined as:
\begin{align}
Rate = (\frac{1}{a})(\frac{-\Delta[A]}{\Delta t}) = (\frac{1}{b})(\frac{-\Delta[B]}{\Delta t}) = (\frac{1}{c}) (\frac{\Delta[C]}{\Delta t}) = (\frac{1}{d})(\frac{\Delta[D]}{\Delta t}) \\
\end{align}
Is there a point of defining the reaction rate as the rate of disappearance of a reactant **over its coefficent**, or the rate of appearance of a product **over its coefficent**? Why not just saying the rate of disappearance of a reactant or the rate of appearance of a product?

Comment: Because then, as your equations show, we would have 4 different rates for a reaction like this. Its much simpler to divide each by the coefficients so that there is one common rate of reaction.

Comment: The question was just marked as a duplicate because it has been answered elsewhere on the site

Answer (score 1):

***There is no defining.***

When you write down the multiplication table, you don't *define* that $2\times4=8$, as if it could have been anything else. Instead, you derive it according to the common rules. Same thing here.

The rate of *anything* is just how many times a second something happens. If we are interested in the rate of reaction, then our "something" stands for **the reaction**, just as written in the equation above, i.e., the act of consuming $a$ moles of $A$, $b$ moles of $B$, etc.

So it goes.